# VS2008 silently dies A LOT when working with WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, crash

When working in VS2008 (C#) does VS2008 silently crash for anybody when working with WPF?  If I touch the XAML it is most likely to crash.  I can come back in, clean, then build, then run and it work until I have to touch the XAML again.  Then start over again.

It is a solution with about 12 projects in it.

Thanks,
jeff

Comment: I have not experienced this issue.  In fact, VS 2008 has been running great for me.  My largest solution with a WPF project in it only has about 7 projects.  I'm running SP1...

Comment: I am running SP1.  I just noticed this in the EventLog.  Doesn't seem like there is a definitive answer as I google this.

Comment: NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (7A097706) (80131506)

Comment: This happens to me all the time too.

Comment: Update to SP1 if you haven't done that yet.

Comment: Try disabling all your plugins and then selectively enabling them until the problem reappears. Then go and make the plugin developer's life miserable ;).

Comment: I have updated to SP1.

I am using CodeRush\Refactor\TestDriven and disabled them. It seems to help some, but the problem is still there.

Answer (score 1):

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=375594

Workaround:

Found real workaround at http://www.dotnet6.com/blogs/wesley_walraeve/archive/2008/10/22/visual-studio-2008-sp1-crashes-toolbox-gt-choose-items.aspx, which was removing TFS Power Commands 2008.  Other people have had to remove other things.

Comment: Not quite it. I've disabled my add-ins with the same problem. I might try and remove them next.

Comment: PowerCommands, in particular, causes crashes like this.  I used to get consistent crashing on rendering a WPF Window in design mode.  When I removed PowerCommands, the crashes went away.  REMOVE, don't just disable.

Answer (score 1):

SP1 solves a bit of the crashes,  but indeed it crashes a lot. Especially when you mix and match winforms + WPF. The crashes alone were a reason to stick with winforms for a while for us ...

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem to be with the AnkhSvn plug-in.  I went to a nightlybuild and it is working good now.  Anything above 2.0.6110.379.

Answer (score 0):

I and some other people at my company have had a lot of problems when editing a resource dictionary and while a XAML window that uses that resource dictionary is open. Moral of the story, close all XAML windows if you're going to edit a resource dictionary.

Comment: There seems to be some correlation with the resource dictionary and xaml.  But I have tried closing all XAML windows before working on a resource dictionary.  At this point, I am looking to edit xaml and resource dictionaries outside of Vs2008.

Answer (score 0):

We suffer the same problems... I noticed that resharper makes things worse for the WPF editor from time to time...

Ah well.. a daily VS crash keeps the doctor away ?

Answer (score 0):

VS crashes at my computer very often: several times per day when I work with WPF. But usually it stops responding and I don't remember it to crash silently.

Answer (score 0):

I know, it's not nice, but simply cleaning the solution works for me. At least until the next restart of VS, but until then you shouldn't get any crashes.